# On existence of polyhedra with a fixed number of edges per face

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory, polyhedra

Let $P$ be a convex polyhedra such that each face has exactly $A$ edges. Denote with $V$, $E$ and $F$ the number of vertices, edges and faces of $P$ respectively. Since each face has $A$ edges we get that $E=\frac{AF}{2}$. This means that $A$ and $F$ cannot be both odd. The graph $G$ induced by $P$ is a planar graph such that each vertex has at least degree $3$. This means we can use Euler's formula to get the amount of vertices: 
$$V=2+E-F=\frac{4 + AF -2F}{2}.$$
**Question**

- For which values of $A$ and $F$ does such a convex polyhedron exist?
- If such a polyhedron exists, how many such non-isomorphic polyhedra exist? By isomorphism I mean that their respective skeleton graphs are isomorphic as graphs.

**Partial results**

The average degree $d$ of $G$ is equal to $d=\frac{2E}{V}=\frac{2AF}{4+(A-2)F}$. Since each vertex has at least degree $3$ we get that $3 \leq d$. Since $G$ is planar we also have that $d < 6$. This two inequalities give restrictions to the possibilities of $A$ and $F$: $3 \leq d$ gives that
$$A \leq \frac{6F-12}{F}.$$
The inequality $d < 6$ gives that
$$\frac{3F-6}{F} < A.$$
This gives us that $A < 6$. We also have that $3 \leq A$ since a face of a polyhedron has at least $3$ edges.
The above inequalities and the fact that $F \geq 0$ give

- If $A=3$, then $F \in [4, \infty)$
- If $A=4$, then $F \in [6, \infty)$
- If $A=5$, then $F \in [12, \infty)$

Denote with $\mathcal{E}$ the set of all even numbers. Since $A$ and $F$ cannot be both odd we have that

- If $A=3$, then $F \in \mathcal{E} \cap [4, \infty) $
- If $A=4$, then $F \in [6, \infty)$
- If $A=5$, then $F \in \mathcal{E} \cap [12, \infty)$

Comment: I deleted my previous comment since Dehn-Sommerville relations only apply to simplicial polytope. Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: For $A=3$, I think we can find such a polyhedron by induction. For $F=4$, this is just a tetrahedron. Now suppose there exists a convex polyhedron $P$ with $F=n$ and $A=3$. If we paste a tetrahedron on one face, we get a polyhedron with $F=n+2$ and $A=3$. This new polyhedron is not necessarily convex, but choosing the height of this pasted tetrahedron small enough, will make it convex.

Comment: The same can be done with pentagonal faces, but with an increment of 10.  In the induction step you use a regular dodecahedron (or a distorted version with the same planar graph).  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609854/possible-all-pentagon-polyhedra.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I actually have induction arguments for all cases. I should post it as an answer once I get the chance.

Comment: As long as you do not predict the existence of a pentagonal 14-hedron :-S it will be good to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the duals of the convex polyhedra where each vertex is $A$-valent, which you might have an easier time finding information on. The graphs of these dual polyhedra are all the $A$-regular 3-connected planar graphs.

#### Case $A = 3.$

You want polyhedra with all faces being triangles, which are the simplicial polyhedra. Wikipedia has a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_polytope) of several classes of these. They exist for any even number of faces greater than two. One example with $2n$ faces for any $n > 2$ is the $n$-gonal bipyramid.

The graphs of the duals are 3-regular (aka cubic) 3-connected planar graphs. The number of non-isomorphic such graphs with 10 to 20 vertices can be found at [Gordon Royle's page](http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/~00013890/remote/cubicplanar/index.html), or as [OEIS A000109](http://oeis.org/A000109).

\begin{array}{| c | c |} \hline
F &  \text{#} \\ \hline
4 & 1 \\
6 & 1 \\
8 & 2 \\
10 & 5 \\
12 & 14 \\
14 & 50 \\
16 & 233 \\
18 & 1249 \\
20 & 7595 \\ 
22  &  49566  \\
24  &  339722  \\
26  &  2406841  \\
28  &  17490241  \\
30  &  129664753  \\ \hline
\end{array}

As you can see, there are a lot.

#### Case $A = 4.$

You want polyhedra with all faces being quadrilaterals. (These are the 3-dimensional cubical polytopes.)
Such polyhedra exist with $2n$ faces for any $n \geq 3$: the [trapezohedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezohedron), aka deltohedra, which are duals to antiprisms.

Quadrilateral-faced polyhedra also exist with $3n$ faces for any $n \geq 3$, by taking an $n$-gonal bipyramid and truncating each vertex on the equatorial $n$-gon to the midpoints of the equatorial edges (making a ring of rhombi around the equator), as described in [this answer of achille hui](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/462966/59435) for $n = 5$.
When $n=3$ you get the [Herschel enneahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herschel_graph):

[image: Herschel enneahedron]

There are no quadrilateral-faced heptahedra.

Given a quadrilateral-faced polyhedron, we can "glue" an irregular cube to one of its faces to get a quadrilateral-faced polyhedron with four more faces. 
Starting from the Herschel enneahedron, you can thus get $F$ faces for any $F \geq 9$ equivalent to 1 mod 4.

The program [plantri](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/) will generate all non-isomorphic 3-connected planar quadrangulations, which are equivalent to quadrilateral-faced convex polyhedra, and finds:

\begin{array}{| c | c |} \hline
F & \text{#} \\ \hline
6  &  1  \\
7  &  0  \\
8  &  1  \\
9  &  1  \\
10  &  3  \\
11  &  3  \\
12  &  11  \\
13  &  18  \\
14  &  58  \\
15  &  139  \\
16  &  451  \\
17  &  1326  \\
18  &  4461  \\
19  &  14554  \\
20  &  49957  \\
21  &  171159  \\
22  &  598102  \\
23  &  2098675  \\
24  &  7437910  \\
25  &  26490072  \\
26  &  94944685  \\
27  &  341867921  \\
28  &  1236864842  \\
29  &  4493270976  \\
30  &  16387852863  \\
31  &  59985464681  \\ \hline
\end{array}

([OEIS A007022](http://oeis.org/A007022)).

Since there are quadrilateral-faced 11-hedra, we can do the same cube-gluing operation to get any $F \geq 11$ equivalent to 3 mod 4.

Thus, for $A=4$ we can have 6 faces, or any number greater than 7.

#### Case $A = 5.$

There are again lots of examples.
Suppose that the polyhedron has $v_k$ vertices of valence $k$.
You can specify the number of vertices of each valence, $(v_3, v_4, v_5, \dotsc)$, and such a polyhedron exists with all pentagonal faces so long as 
$v_4 \geq 6$ and $v_3 = 20 + \sum_{k \geq 4} (3k - 10) v_k$,
by a result of J.C. Fisher in [Five-valent convex polyhedra with prescribed faces](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(75)90061-8).
So the total number of vertices is
$$
V = 20 + \sum_{k \geq 4} (3k - 9) v_k,
$$
and since $V = \frac{3F}{2} + 2$, the total number of faces is
$$
F = 12 + 2\sum_{k \geq 4}(k-3)v_k.
$$
By setting $v_4$ to any integer at least 6, and all other $v_k = 0$,
we can guarantee the existence of pentagonal-faced polyhedra with any even number of faces greater than or equal to 24.

There are also pentagonal-faced polyhedra with 12 faces (the dodecahedron), 16 faces (the dual of the [snub square antiprism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_square_antiprism)), 18 or 20 faces (the polyhedra with planar graphs shown below), and 22 faces (the result of gluing two regular dodecahedra together along a face, as described in [this answer of Oscar Lanzi](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2100970/59435).)
(The 20-faced pentagonal planar graph is the dual of the so-called [20-quintic graph 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=20-quintic+graph+1).)

[image: Pentagonal planar graphs with 18 and 20 faces]

The same answer of Oscar Lanzi, in the question [Possible all-Pentagon Polyhedra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1609854/59435), asserts that there are no pentagon-faced polyhedra with 14 faces.  The Fisher article cited above provides @Oscar's reference for the nonexistence of a pentagonal 14-hedron.

Using [plantri](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/) and countg (from the [nauty gtools](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/)), we can count the number of 5-regular 3-connected planar graphs, to enumerate the number of isomorphism classes:

\begin{array}{| c | c |} \hline
F &  \text{#} \\ \hline
12 & 1 \\
14 & 0 \\
16 & 1 \\
18 & 1 \\
20 & 6 \\
22 & 14 \\
24 & 96 \\
26 & 518 \\
28 & 3917 \\
30 & 29821 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Yes for 18 and 22, no for 14.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609854/possible-all-pentagon-polyhedra.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: thanks for reminding me--I see that I answered that question, 15 months ago! Added to answer.